# Firing a manual click event on an button in ember.js doesn't give the required result

Tags: javascript, ember.js

TL;DR: Trying to fire a manual javascript click event on the chat button of twitch, won't send the message. Don't understand why the event doesn't do the same as a normal click and don't know how to make it work.

So I am trying to make a custom bot for twitch.tv, only reading his info from the HTML directly. I've got it perfectly working up to the point at where it can recognize commands and put text in the textbox. Now the problem I have is, as soon as I try to fire a manual click event on the "chat" button, it just doesn't seem to work. My guess is it has something to do with ember.js, and I frankly don't know anything about that. Anyway, here is the part of the code that doesn't work. EDIT: this works if I enter it as single in the console, doesn't work in context of the rest of my code though.

```
$('.send-chat-button').click();
```

What happens here is that I acquire a piece of html that contains the chat submit button, which is this:

```
<button class="button primary float-right send-chat-button" data-bindattr-3945="3945">
  <span>
    Chat
  </span>
</button>
```

When I try to manually fire a click event on this, nothing happens. However, when I fire a manual click event on buttonContain.children[0] and buttonContain.children[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo7b6.png) (which are, respectively, the settings and list of viewers buttons), it does work. They look like this:

```
<a data-ember-action="3943" class="button glyph-only float-left" title="Chat Settings"></a>
```

I'm guessing the difference is in the data-ember-action and the data-bindattr-*, but I don't know how to make it work. Anyone here knows why the click() event doesn't work and directly clicking does?

EDIT: If you have any questions about my question, feel free to ask.

EDIT2: I experimented a little more, and I can remove all HTML attributes from the button, and clicking on it will still work. I have no idea what is going on :(.

EDIT3: Okay, so it seems it only stops working when i remove the 
    Span within the button 
Still no idea what is going on. (Yes, have also tried to fire the click event on the span)

EDIT4: As requested, here is all the code from my side. Note that I'm trying to click a button from twitch itself, of which ember side I do not own any code. This code is used by pasting it in the console on a twitch.tv stream and then starting it by calling initiateMessageProcessing. I'm sorry for the lot of hardcoded values, those are twitch' fields that I need. For now I'm just looking for a proof of concept.

```
var frequency = 5000;
var myInterval = 0;
var lastMessageId = 0;

function initiateMessageProcessing() {
    if (myInterval > 0) {
        clearInterval(myInterval);
    }

    myInterval = setInterval("checkMessages()", frequency);
}

function checkMessages() {
    var chat = document.getElementsByClassName("chat-lines")[0];
    processMessages(extractUnprocessedMessages(chat.children));
    lastMessageId = parseInt(chat.lastElementChild.getAttribute("id").substring(5, 10));
}

function extractUnprocessedMessages(chat) {
    var unprocessedMessages = [];
    var chatId = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < chat.length; i++) {
        chatId = parseInt(chat[i].getAttribute("id").substring(5, 10));
        if (chatId > lastMessageId) {
            unprocessedMessages.push(chat[i]);
        }
    }
    return unprocessedMessages;
}

function processMessages(unprocessedMessages) {
    var messageElement;
    for ( i = 0; i < unprocessedMessages.length; i++) {
        messageElement = unprocessedMessages[i].children[0].getElementsByClassName("message")[0];
        if (messageElement != undefined && messageElement != null) {
            if (messageElement.innerHTML.search("!test") !== -1) {
                sendMessage('Hello world!');
            }
        }
    }
}

function sendMessage(message) {
    fillTextArea(message);
    var button = $('.send-chat-button').get(0);
    var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
        bubbles : true
    });
    button.dispatchEvent(event);
}

function fillTextArea(message){
    var textArea;
    var chatInterface = document.getElementsByClassName("chat-interface")[0];
    var textAreaContain = chatInterface.children[0];
    textArea = textAreaContain.children[0].children[0];
    textArea.value = message;
}
```

EDIT5: Eventlistener screenshot: [image: eventlistener]

EDIT6: Edited source code to use $('.send-chat-button').click();
I have tried this, does not work in the current code, it does work if I manually fire this single command in the console when there is text in the chat. But sadly does not work in my code.

EDIT7: used Ember.run, still doesn't work.

EDIT8: used dispatchmouseevent, still doesn't work in context of code

Comment: Provide more code please.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, I added all my code to the post!

Comment: on chrome, there's an option to look into event listerns if you go to the elements tab and then right next to the styles tab, there's no garuntee it'll be the be all because it depends how twitch is listening for that click but it might give you a good place to startt

Comment: I did, and there is indeed a listener for the click event on that button, but the handler refers to a minified javascript function, which I can't learn alot from. Adding screenshot of the listener to main post.

Comment: You should wrap the code with an `Ember.run()` in order for ember to do it's thing after your code.

Comment: Try `$('.send-chat-button').click()` and see if that works. I just did that live on the twitch.tv site and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @Kitler, It tried, it says run is not defined, I don't think run is the problem here.

Comment: @Mike1o1: see main post edit, it does indeed work, but somehow not in the context of my code.

Comment: `Ember.run(function() { Ember.$('.send-chat-button').click() });` ... or App if you're not using the `ember-cli``

Comment: Used this (see updated source code), no errors, but no improvement in functionality :(

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the target site attaches event listeners without help of JQuery. If it is so, you cannot trigger it using jquery .click() method.

You can try directly mocking the browser event like this:

```
var button = $('.send-chat-button').get(0);
var event = new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true});
button.dispatchEvent(event);
```

This code will not work in IE8 and lower, but I guess it is not your case.

Comment: The only problem being that the click() method does work, but not in the context of my code, it's the same with your method.

Comment: Are you sure your click event does not work? I've just went to the site (http://www.twitch.tv/mr_morjus) and wrote in console $('.send-chat-button').click(), and the site requested my login to post the message...

Comment: That does work, but not in the context of my complete code, I'll update my complete code in the main post now

Comment: The sendMessage() finction is never called because of this condition: messageElement.innerHTML.search("!test") !== -1 . I've replaced !== with === and run your code. It asked me to log in...

Comment: No, that is what I'm trying to achieve, as soon as someone says "!test", I have to output something, and yes it asks you to login if you're not logged in, but it doesn't send it when you are logged in.

Comment: The problem is clearly not in event processing. The event triggering works perfectly fine. Sorry, I will not register there to dig this deeper.

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is quite old but I had been looking for an answer on this for a while and nothing really worked, after trying out A LOT of stuff I found it works when you focus the chatbox first then focus the button then triggering the click event!!! uuuhm yeah...

```
$('.chat_text_input').focus();
$('.send-chat-button').focus().trigger('click');
```

I have no idea why this works (and why it doesn't in any other way), but leaving any of the focusses out makes it fail or bug out.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically clicking a DOM element to make some action done is somewhat a wrong approach.

You should have define a method myAction() which will be called in two ways. First, from your ember action triggerMyAction() and second, after listening to a custom event, "myEvent".

Instead of $('.send-chat-button').click(); you will code $('something').trigger("myEvent") then.

Something like:

```
Em.Controller.extend({

    myAction:function(){
      //do your stuff
    },

    onMyEvent:function(){
        $('something').on('myEvent',this.myAction);
    }.on('didInsertElement'),

    actions:{
        triggerMyAction:function(){
            this.myAction();
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: In this case, myAction is clicking on the button, so this would not work. I have no idea what Twitch does after I click on the button (minified javascript), so can't call that directly.